# Does DDD and Automapper defeat lazy loading?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, automapper

I'm working on an n-Tier Domain Driven Design project that uses Entity Framework 4 DB-First and Automapper to produce POCO's in the Domain's namespace.

To clarify: The EF project returns entities in the **MyProject.Repositories.EF.Entities** namespace and I use Automapper to turn them into entities in the **MyProject.Domain.Entities** namespace.

Now, I can't quite make out if when I map between the EF and Domain entities, if all the collection properties are enumerated, i.e. if all the related data is also retrieved from the DB when they are mapped, or if they are still only lazy loaded when I actually enumerate them in code.

I am concerned about the obvious performance implications.

Comment: Why not Code-First? You would avoid some problems..

Comment: Client explicitly asked for DB first.

Comment: Are you referring to using Project.To ?

Comment: No. http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer is no. As long as you map between two IEnumerables, the actual enumeration will only take place when you perform a foreach, ToList(), etc. If you don't perform actions on IEnumerable properties of these objects, the enumeration will never happen and the related data will not be retrieved.

Comment: I think this is wrong. I'm currently having this problem, and my navigation property on my DAL entity is loaded just by mapping from ICollection to ICollection.

Comment: @victor ICollection is going to have to be realized(it has a Count). Only IEnumerable can by generated during iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short - this is not a concern of AutoMapper, but of how you use your ORM. AutoMapper merely removes code you would have already written, so if you would have written lousy performing code against your ORM, AutoMapper will happily oblige.

People were abusing ORMs before AutoMapper, while using AutoMapper, and after using AutoMapper. Lazy loading is a powerful tool when used correctly, but still can be abused. Using lazy loading does not preclude the developer from understanding what is actually happening underneath the covers.

So use AutoMapper, but take care with your fetching, just as you should be doing had you NOT used AutoMapper.

Comment: The question is whether automapper enumerates the IQueryable collection properties or not.